# I was unable to locate element for login id?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"usr"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'VINAY-PM', ip: '1.255.255.52', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\Users\PRATIB~1.PAW\AppDa...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57978}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 4cd68fb307810caaea51329ab426fab4
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=usr}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at demo.login.main(login.java:20)
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<label for="usr" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">eg. yourname@company.com</label>
<input type="text" name="userName" size="30" value="" onkeyup="submitPage(event);" id="usr">
```

Please help me out

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is related to this - **Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds**

Are you sure that the page already loaded all the info when you are searching for the element ? You can always wait for the element with X amount time timeout.

Can you share how are you locating the element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the definition of WebDriver outside of Main. Also you had the right idea with using wait so I'd re-enable that.

e.g.

```
public class login {

public WebDriver wd;
public WebDriverWait wait;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//rani//Desktop//rani//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");

     wd =new ChromeDriver();
     wd.get("http://1.255.255.18:9895/TnEV1_0AWeb/");

     //probably no longer needed
     Thread.sleep(10000);

     //wd.findElement(By.id("usr")).sendKeys("selenium");

     wait=new WebDriverWait(wd, 60); 
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userName"))); 
     wd.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("selenium");

}
}
```